# Pinned Conflicts while installing Glueviz

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, astronomy, astroquery

I want to install the Glueviz software using ananconda python distribution, but unable to do so. Here are the steps I did in the anaconda shell

1. `conda update -n root conda`
2. `conda create -n glueviz-env python`
3. `conda activate glueviz-env`
4. `conda install -c glueviz glueviz`

After this it showed me an error.

```
Channels:
 - glueviz
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package glueviz-1.2.4-h06a4308_0 requires glue-core 1.2.4, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ glueviz 1.2**  is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ glueviz 1.2.4 would require
│  │  └─ glue-core 1.2.4  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ glue-core 1.2.4 would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core 1.2.4 would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core 1.2.4 would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core 1.2.4 would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core 1.2.4 would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     └─ glue-core 1.2.4 would require
│  │        └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ glueviz 1.2.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ glueviz 1.2.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ glueviz 1.2.0 would require
│     └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
- python 3.12.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

I tried this following modification as mentioned [here](https://github.com/conda/conda-libmamba-solver/issues/350)-
`CONDA_CHANNEL_PRIORITY=flexible conda install -c glueviz glueviz`

but nothing worked. This is my output

```
Channels:
 - glueviz
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides numpy 1.8* needed by glueviz-0.4.0-np18py33_0

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ glueviz is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ glueviz 0.4.0 would require
│  │  └─ numpy 1.8* , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  ├─ glueviz [0.4.0|0.7.3|...|0.9.0] would require
│  │  └─ python 2.7* , which can be installed;
│  ├─ glueviz [0.4.0|0.7.3|...|0.9.0] would require
│  │  └─ python 3.4* , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  ├─ glueviz 0.4.0 would require
│  │  └─ python 3.3* , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  ├─ glueviz [0.10.0|0.9.1] would require
│  │  └─ pyqt 4.11.* , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  ├─ glueviz [0.7.3|0.8.0|0.8.1|0.8.2|0.9.0] would require
│  │  └─ python 3.5* , which can be installed;
│  ├─ glueviz [0.10.1|0.10.2] would require
│  │  └─ glue-core [>=0.10.1 |>=0.10.2 ] with the potential options
│  │     ├─ glue-core [0.13.3|0.13.4|...|1.2.4] would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core [0.10.2|0.10.3|...|0.15.6] would require
│  │     │  └─ python [2.7* |>=2.7,<2.8.0a0 ], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core [0.10.2|0.10.3|...|0.15.6] would require
│  │     │  └─ python [3.5* |>=3.5,<3.6.0a0 ], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core [0.10.2|0.10.3|...|1.7.0] would require
│  │     │  └─ python [3.6* |>=3.6,<3.7.0a0 ], which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core [0.15.6|1.0.0|...|1.2.4] would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core [0.15.6|1.0.0|...|1.2.4] would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core [1.0.1|1.2.4] would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core 1.2.4 would require
│  │     │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     ├─ glue-core 1.0.1 would require
│  │     │  └─ scikit-image with the potential options
│  │     │     ├─ scikit-image [0.13.0|0.13.1|0.14.0|0.14.1|0.14.2] would require
│  │     │     │  └─ python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     │     ├─ scikit-image [0.13.0|0.13.1|0.14.0] would require
│  │     │     │  └─ python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     │     ├─ scikit-image [0.13.0|0.13.1|...|0.17.2] would require
│  │     │     │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     │     ├─ scikit-image [0.14.0|0.14.1|...|0.19.3] would require
│  │     │     │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     │     ├─ scikit-image [0.15.0|0.16.2|...|0.20.0] would require
│  │     │     │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     │     ├─ scikit-image [0.16.2|0.18.3|0.19.2|0.19.3|0.20.0] would require
│  │     │     │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     │     ├─ scikit-image [0.16.2|0.17.2|...|0.20.0] would require
│  │     │     │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     │     └─ scikit-image [0.19.3|0.20.0] would require
│  │     │        └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │     └─ glue-core [0.10.1|0.10.2] would require
│  │        └─ pyqt 4.11.* , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  ├─ glueviz 0.8.2 would require
│  │  └─ pyqt 4.* , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  ├─ glueviz [0.10.3|0.10.4|...|1.0.0] would require
│  │  └─ glue-core [>=0.10.3 |>=0.10.4 |...|>=0.15.5 ], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  ├─ glueviz [1.0.0|1.1.0|1.2.0] would require
│  │  ├─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │  └─ python_abi 3.8.* *_cp38, which requires
│  │     └─ python 3.8.* , which can be installed;
│  ├─ glueviz [1.0.0|1.1.0|1.2.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ glueviz 1.0.0 would require
│  │  ├─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │  └─ python_abi 3.6.* *_cp36m, which requires
│  │     └─ python 3.6.* , which can be installed;
│  ├─ glueviz [1.0.0|1.1.0|1.2.0] would require
│  │  ├─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  │  └─ python_abi 3.7.* *_cp37m, which requires
│  │     └─ python 3.7.* , which can be installed;
│  └─ glueviz 1.2.4 would require
│     └─ glue-core 1.2.4 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.12.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.12.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

I will be grateful if anyone helps me with this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `glueviz-feedstock` has [not yet successfully rebuilt for Python 3.12](https://github.com/conda-forge/glueviz-feedstock/pull/51) (a.k.a., *migrated* for Python 3.12). Generally, one should prefer specifying all requirements at creation time. Also, the `glueviz` channel has not updated the `glueviz` package for a couple years, so I would not recommend using that. Try something like

```bash
conda create -n glueviz-env -c conda-forge glueviz python=3.11
```

Or use a lower Python version.

---

#### Note on solve speeds

In test solving, I see a fresh `glueviz` environment needs to install 300+ packages, which means a formidable solve. I wouldn't try that with anything but Mamba or the latest Conda (which now uses `libmamba` as its solver). But one can slightly speed up the solve by prespecifying some things, e.g.,

```bash
mamba create -n glueviz-env -c conda-forge \
  python=3.11 glueviz==1.2.0 glue-core==1.17.1
```

That still takes ~40 seconds to solve.

Comment: I tried this. It asks me to remove the existing venv. After proceeding my terminal keeps crashing and it closes.

Comment: Well that's a bug to report to Conda. You'll need to give them details about your system, terminal, shell, and what version of Conda you are using.

Comment: @SusnataChattopadhyay is it crashing removing the environment or after that? (Check `conda env list` to see if the environment is removed)

Comment: Yes the environment is removed. But when I run the given code again, it crashes while collecting metadata.

Comment: Are you resource limited? E.g., running out of RAM?

Comment: @SusnataChattopadhyay I added a note on solve speeds. The `glueviz` package is a massive solve that involves 300+ packages - crazy. So if you are on a resource-constrained system, you may want to add some specific package versions so that Conda doesn't try to grok the entire solve space. Or use something like prefix.dev to do the environment solve for you and use the resulting conda-lock file.

Comment: I have 4GB RAM. Ok I will try them and let you know.